# Netbeans always running maven build before debugging

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am running Netbeans 8.0.2 and I am trying to debug a web app. This app is a module in a larger suite. Normally just the parent gets compiled which set's up property values for db connections etc. So, that being said the web app I am trying to debug never gets built independently.

So, I want to be able to do right-click > debug without netbeans running the maven build (this will mess up the prop values).

I have the "Always perform build before running application" unchecked in the Run configuration. But every single time, it builds it anyways!

Is there something I'm missing? Or is there some bug in Netbeans?

Edit: I've also tried deleting the cache.

Comment: Is there maybe a separate Run and Debug configuration?

Comment: @Burkhard there is the Actions > Run & Actions > Debug but those don't have anything regarding building before running.

Comment: Really? Nobody else on earth has this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question which you probably (and hopefully) solved already. However, as I had the same problem and could not find an answer here, I want to share my solution to this problem for others.

My application also first built itself and then started debugging. I checked the run/debug configuration and they were fine. So I deleted the local maven repositories of all dependencies of my application and rebuilt them. Seems like NetBeans confused something with the dependencies and therefore rebuilt the application every single time again. After deleting and rebuilding the dependencies I was able again to debug the application without building it before.